# Minus value in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried the following query (using standard catalog views - note that one subquery uses a dblink):

```
SELECT (MAX(sequence#)-(SELECT MAX(sequence#) a FROM v$log_history@standby 
WHERE first_time > SYSDATE - 1)) FROM v$log_history where first_time > SYSDATE - 1
```

This should produce a single integer. But I got the following error: "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function" even though the subquery is scalar, and then the outer query should also be scalar (selecting max over all rows). What is wrong with my query, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't Success"?  The query is correct and it does exactly what you described. So what happened when you tried? "It isn't Success" doesn't tell us what the problem is, so how do you want us to help you?

Comment: Sorry because I had summary it. I have 2 server run DataGuard. Now, i want to check status Dataguard via using query on Primary. I try this query on Primary, but it isn't success.SELECT
 (MAX(sequence#)-(SELECT
            MAX(sequence#) a
        FROM
            v$log_history@standby
        WHERE
            first_time > SYSDATE - 1))
FROM
    v$log_history
where
    first_time > SYSDATE - 1

Comment: OK, you showed us a good query but now you say it wasn't the query you had trouble with. But in the comment, **AGAIN**, you tell us that the problem is "it isn't success". WHAT THE HECK DOES THAT **MEAN**?

Comment: when i run it, it has error "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out from reading the code.

Comment: I re-wrote your QUESTION from scratch, because what you posted initially had absolutely nothing to do with your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's happening. Oracle is not able to see that the scalar subquery is constant, and it will complain that it is not a group by column or expression.

Try like this:

```
SELECT MAX(sequence#-(SELECT MAX(sequence#) 
                      FROM v$log_history@standby
                      WHERE first_time > SYSDATE - 1))
FROM v$log_history
where first_time > SYSDATE - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
What you are lacking is an aggregate function on the expression 
---> SELECT MAX(sequence#) 
       FROM v$log_history@standby 
      WHERE first_time > SYSDATE - 1
```

I would try by setting the alias on the table/views also as a better way to reference the query accurately.

```
SELECT MAX(db.sequence#)-MAX (
                              (SELECT MAX(other_db.sequence#) 
                                FROM v$log_history@standby other_db
                                WHERE other_db.first_time > SYSDATE - 1
                              )
                             )
  FROM v$log_history db
 WHERE db.first_time > SYSDATE - 1
```